# Calculating downloading/uploading speed error

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a problem with my download/upload speed calculator. 
I write down the numbers to the "inputBox", and I think it can't parse it. 
Here's the source code:

!UPDATED!

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

namespace Tomco_DownloadTime {
    public partial class Form1 : Form {
        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
            timeLabel.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm tt");
        }

        IPv4InterfaceStatistics stat = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces() [0].GetIPv4Statistics();

        private double getKBDownloadSpeed() {
            return (stat.BytesReceived)/1024;
        }

        private double getMBDownloadSpeed() {
            return ((stat.BytesReceived)/1024)/1024;
        }

        private double getGBDownloadSpeed() {
            return (((stat.BytesReceived)/1024)/1024)/1024;
        }

        private double getKBUploadSpeed() {
             return (stat.BytesSent)/1024;
        }

        private double getMBUploadSpeed() {
             return ((stat.BytesSent)/1024)/1024;
        }

        private double getGBUploadSpeed() {
            return (((stat.BytesSent)/1024)/1024)/1024;
        }

        private void startButton_Click(object sender,EventArgs e) {
            this.Width = 335;
            this.Height = 154;
            double size = double.Parse(inputBox.Text);

            if(roundingCheckBox.Checked == true) {
                if(downloadCheckBox.Checked == true) {
                    // download
                    if(kbCheckBox.Checked) {
                        sizeTypeLabel.Text = "Size (KB):";
                        double kbSpeed = size / getKBDownloadSpeed();
                        outputLabel.Text = kbSpeed.ToString();
                    } 
                    if(mbCheckBox.Checked) {
                        sizeTypeLabel.Text = "Size (MB):";
                    }
                    if(gbCheckBox.Checked) {
                        sizeTypeLabel.Text = "Size (GB):";
                    }
                }
                if(uploadCheckBox.Checked) {
                        //upload
                    if(kbCheckBox.Checked) {
                        sizeTypeLabel.Text = "Size (KB):";
                    }
                    if(mbCheckBox.Checked) {
                        sizeTypeLabel.Text = "Size (MB):";
                    }
                    if(gbCheckBox.Checked) {
                        sizeTypeLabel.Text = "Size (GB):";
                    }
                }
            } else {

            }
        }

        private void optionsButton_Click(object sender,EventArgs e) {
            this.Width = 335;
            this.Height = 241;
        }
     }
  }
```

Why do I think there's a problem with the parsing? Because if I add the numbers to the inputBox, and press the "Calculate" button, my MessageBox appears, and displays the error.

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint at the calculate button and debugging?

Comment: What number did you input? And did you take care of using a , or . depending on the language/culture settings?

Comment: @Killingsworth I assume he means the error near the end: MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid float number, like this: 3.14","TOMCO DT - ERROR :...

Comment: you may need to remove whitespace from the string, it could be messing up the TryParse.  The other thing you can do is switch to double.Parse and let it throw an exception.

Comment: Just a small note: you can remove all the '== true' texts, those are not needed since the Checked attribute is a boolean itself and can be used directly as (boolean) expression.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the MessageBox.Show() and tell us what the text in your textbox is.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers Good point; I thought we were talking runtime error

Comment: Try use double.Parse - if value in inputBox.Text weren't correct, you'll see an exception. It'd be your guideline to solve the problem.

Comment: @Tomc0, tangental to your problem but a easier way to switch between bytes and Gigabytes instead of doing `/1024)/1024)/1024` you can do `/(1 << 30)`. The `<<` is the [Left Shift operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_left_shift), every 10 is one of the prefixes (you can even use 0), so `x/(1 << 0)` is bytes, `x/(1 << 10)` is Kilobytes, `x/(1 << 20)` is Megabytes,, `x/(1 << 30)` is Gigabytes. It makes it easy to then make a function that returns `x/(1 << (10 * y))` then you just pass in 0, 1, 2, 3, and so on for `y` and it will convert the unit for you.

Comment: Michel Keijzers: My number was 12.4 and numbers like that. Thanks for the boolean form advice. TheGreatCO: Okay, I will try this out. Scott Chamberlain: Thank you! I will use this form! Gusdor: +  inputBox {Text = "12.45"} System.Windows.Forms.TextBox

Comment: So, I removed the tryParse part, now I have an exception: An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: By the way, how did you expect to get the speed without measuring elapsed time? You're dividing size by total kilobytes received. It looks senseless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this is caused by unrecognized decimal separator. I guess the code is not run under en-US culture.

You can try:

```
double size = 
  double.Parse(inputBox.Text, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: Thanks, working! But now I will need to figure out an other problem... I click the button, and nothing happens... Great.